# Error occurred initializing command object on succeeding command objects in controller

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller

I have the defined following controller

```
class BookController {

  def book(BookCommand bookCommand,
           AnotherBookCommand bookCommand2) 
  {
    ....
  }
```

When I debugged it, binding is done on the bookCommand and when it's bookCommand2's turn  for binding, it throws this exception

```
Error in object 'bookCommand2': codes []; arguments []; default message [Error occurred initializing command object [bookCommand2]. org.apache.groovy.json.internal.Exceptions$JsonInternalException: Wrapped Exception
 CAUSE java.io.IOException :: Stream closed]
```

If I try to switch the order of the parameters i.e.

```
class BookController {

  def book(AnotherBookCommand bookCommand2,
           BookCommand bookCommand) 
  {
    ....
  }
```

Binding is done on the bookCommand2 and binding of bookCommand throws the exception.

```
Error in object 'bookCommand': codes []; arguments []; default message [Error occurred initializing command object [bookCommand]. org.apache.groovy.json.internal.Exceptions$JsonInternalException: Wrapped Exception
 CAUSE java.io.IOException :: Stream closed]
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not support binding the request of the body to multiple command objects.  One option you have is to aggregate them into 1 class with something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    BookCommand bookCommand
    BookCommand anotherBookCommand
}
```

Then have your controller action accept one of those and organize the body of the JSON accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Putting it in one class works. I didn't mention that I was migrating code from older grails version to grails 4 and trying to avoid changing the code so I added  a method interceptor to support multiple command objects for now.

Comment: Great.  Be aware that if you want to bind the body of the request (as distinct from request parameters) to multiple command objects that you will need to read the body once and use it multiple times.  An attempt to read the body twice will result in an exception because it will be empty the second time.